# Не работает mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli, php7.2

```
$categories_org = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `categories`");
$categories = array();
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)) { array_push($categories, $res); }
print_r($categories_org);
```

Почему-то fetch_assoc сразу возвращает false, хотя в таблице 15 строк. С подключением все в порядке. В чем ошибка?

Если что, вот результат вывода $categories_org с помощью print_r:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 4 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 15 [type] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну да, потому что `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` должен применять данные которые вернул `mysqli_query`.

```
$categories_org = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `categories`");
$categories = array();
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories_org)) { array_push($categories, $res); }
print_r($categories);
```

Вам надо ещё раз изучить источник откуда вы черпаете информацию.

Comment: Блин, не заметил. Вот до чего ночной кодинг доводит...

Answer (score 0):

В стиле ООП

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "basa");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) exit("Соединение не удалось");

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM categories")) {
    $categories = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($categories, $row);
        // или
        $categories[] = $row; // так мне кажется лучше
    }
    $result->free();
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно конкретно в процедурном стиле. Не может быть такого, что нельзя реализовать простейшую функцию в процедурном, но можно в ООП.

Comment: @Ikor Dadurii, это для примера